# Variable in makefile conditional?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Apparently there is no boolean type in GNU Make conditionals so this seemed like the best solution:

```
$(DEF_TARGET):
    if [ "$(CHECK)" != "y" ]; then \
            var=foo; \
            $(if $(filter foo,$(var)),result=true,result=false); \
    fi
```

The problem is that no matter if `var=foo` or `var=bar`, `result` will always be `false`. Replacing `$(var)` with `foo` or `bar` will yeld correct result.

Why will this not work? Are there any better solutions to the problem?

Following makefile is run with the command `make -f make.txt`

```
.PHONY: all
all:
     X=aaa; \
     Y=aaa; \
     if [[ '$(filter $(X),$(Y))' ]]; then echo "matched!"; else echo "not matched!"; fi
```

output:

```
X=aaa; \
Y=aaa; \
if [[ '' ]]; then echo "matched!"; else echo "not matched!"; fi
not matched!
```

Why does it fail when `X` and `Y` are assigned values in the target recipe?

Comment: `[ "CHECK" != "y" ]` (a `Shell` conditional, part of the target recipe) compares literal string `"CHECK"` with the literal string `"y"` and will always evaluate true. What is the logic you need to build?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typing error. I want to build an `OR` operation so I can check for multiple words in `$(var)` and have `result=true` if a match is found. In the example I just check for `foo` until I get it to work.

Comment: @PeterSmith the reason that you are having trouble, is that you are trying to do with a makefile recipe, what they are not designed to do.  What you want is best done outside of a recipe, or perhaps even without Make at all, just with a shell script.

Answer (score 7):

> Apparently there is no boolean type in GNU Make conditionals

Clearly [there is](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Functions), else the presence of an `$(if ...)` macro would not make sense!

The way to read recipes
(i.e., the block of shell commands that build the target)
is to understand that *make* stores a recipe as a single recursively expanded variable.
The recipe is only expanded when *make* needs to pass some commands to the shell.

The recipe is expanded once in its entirety.
Each line of the resulting expansion is then executed one-by-one.
Each execution is run in a *new* instance of the shell.

So,
taking your original makefile,
let's assume that you have asked *make* to build `${DEF_TARGET}`.
*Make* expands the recipe:

> ```
> if [ "$(CHECK)" != "y" ]; then \
>         var=foo; \
>         $(if $(filter foo,$(var)),result=true,result=false); \
> fi
> ```

- `${CHECK}` becomes nothing (say)
- `$(if $(filter foo,$(var)),result=true,result=false)`

  - First, `${var}` is expanded and also becomes empty (say).
    Note that the line `var=foo` in the recipe is *not* interpreted by make!
    It is a shell command.
  - Next, `$(filter foo,)` is expanded and also is empty.
  - Next *make* expands `$(if ,result=true,result=false)`, which produces `result=false` of course.

    ```
    if [ "" != "y" ]; then \
       var=foo; \
       result=false; \
    fi
    ```

    *Make* sees this as a just one line due to the back-slashes.

So,
do not confuse shell variables and *make* variables.
All the *make* variables are gone by the time the shell gets its hands on the recipe.
*Make* does not know anything about shell variables.

Your original shell snippet could be something like:

```
result=$(if $(filter y,${CHECK}),true,false)
```

(TIMTOWTDI applies).
The shell gets `result=true` or `result=false` depending on the value of the *make* variable `CHECK`.

Comment: Conclusion: I try to do something with a tool I don't understand well enough.  I will try and fix that now.

Answer (score 0):

Makefile

```
.PHONY: all
all:
        @echo "$(filter $(X),$(Y))"
```

Tests

```
$ make -f make.txt X='xxx yyy' Y='aaa bbb'

$ make -f make.txt X='xxx yyy' Y='aaa xxx'
xxx
$ make -f make.txt X='bbb yyy' Y='aaa bbb'
bbb
```

GNU Bash treats non empty strings as `true` in a boolean context. So a recipe with shell level condition might be:

```
all:
        if [[ '$(filter $(X),$(Y))' ]]; then echo "matched!"; else echo "not matched!"; fi
```

Comment: Your example works fine when `X` and `Y` are assigned values on the command line, but when I try to assign them in the target recipe it fails. I have updated the question with an example. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Recipe is fully evaluated by the makefile before the control passed to it. You can use `$(shell ...)` macro to get output of a shell command.